# First click does not trigger alert

Tags: javascript

Have a look at this simple function:

```
handleEventClick(i){  
   this.setState({choosenDriver: this.state.drivers[i]});
   alert(i);
   for (let ix in this.state.choosenDriver.cars) {
   alert(ix);               
    }
 }
```

What I would expect to happen is that both `alert(i)` and `alert(ix)` should get triggered when I click.

For some reason `alert(ix)` does not fire on the first click but works as it should from the second click. `alert(i)` however works as it should.

Can someone explain this?
Thank you!

Update:

Than you both for answering. Im sure that you have already explained the problem but I still dont understand.

Now I try this:

```
handleEventClick(i){
   this.setState({choosenDriver: this.state.drivers[i]});
   let a = this.state.choosenDriver.cars;

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, function(child) {
    // Do something with `child`
   alert(child);
});
```

And on the first click it generates the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined
```

But I DO define choosenDriver on the first line BEFORE looping through it so I dont understand why I get this error.

Comment: Clearly, `this.state.choosenDriver.cars` has no own properties so you don't see `alert(ix)` for the first time.

Comment: @dfsq: Sounds like an answer. :-) (Except it wouldn't have to be an *own* property, inherited ones would also show up. *Enumerable*, yes, but *own*, no.)

Comment: @ Roger: If `cars` is an array, note that that's almost certainly not now you should loop through its entries. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) gives you a list of ways, but either use `forEach` or similar, or (at least) add a `hasOwnProperty` check inside the loop.

Comment: But in the functions first line :  this.setState({choosenDriver: this.state.drivers[i]}); its gets it values. Or am I wrong?

Comment: cars is an Array, I will look at your link!
But you dont Think its a good idea to loop through the [cars] at this Place in the code? Im not sure where else to do it, everytime choosenDriver Changes, that is where i need to do something with the cars.